# AUTOSAR's Data concistency

Tags: autosar

After reading `AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate`, I'm still confused about both types of `InterRunnableVariable` and concepts of data consistency. There are my question:

1. What is the difference between `ExplicitInterRunnableVariable` and
   `ImplicitRunnableVariable`?
2. Can `InterRunnableVariable` be processed by another `RunnableEntity` from a different software component?
3. Can AUTOSAR's software component read or write directly to the RAM with given spesific address?
4. What is the condition where we have to use `ExclusiveArea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ref: TPS_SWCT_01054 and TPS_SWCT_01055
2. Ref: TPS_SWCT_01592
3. Software-component are written in C, and C (as is known) gives you enough rope to hang yourself. The question is not whether they can but whether they should (outside of the formal modeling).
4. There is no condition, *exclusive areas* simply represent a mechanism for mutual exclusion. Use *exclusive areas* if you need to implement mutual exclusion **and** don't feel like using *inter-runnable variables*.

Comment: Thanks again Uwe, You will get a lot of reputation from my questions. (Kidding). Finally, my company is about to get me the configuration tool (SystemDesk).

2. I suppose the answer is yes, but has to through via port. 

3. I have developed a embedded system, but in that system I directly access the RAM to store or read the data. To migration to AUTOSAR, what do you suggest to change that method? Is the InterRunnableVariable enough?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you mean by "directly accessing the RAM". There are ways of doing that which are safe in an AUTOSAR environment and there are ways that are less safe. It depends.

Comment: Besides *inter-runnable variables* it would also be possible to use *per-instance memory*. But again, whether this would be more appropriate depends on the use case.

Comment: My software component doesn't support multiple instance, so I don't think _per-instance memory_ will be neccessary. I created illustration to illustrate my comprehension about interrunnablevariable, [please check it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DaiBG2VtgOTmlDZENfTXhDWVk/view?usp=sharing), is interRunnableVariable's position is true?

Comment: Thanks again uwe, futhermore question in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571382/autosar-inter-runnable-entity-communication)